# Помогите разобрать ErrorLog

Tags: android

Бывают иногда такие случаи когда все работало и вдруг не работает. Видимо случается такое, потому что иначе объяснить то, что произошло я не могу.
Работал над проектом, все было нормально, запускал Run несколько раз, все было нормально, добавил в layout textview, оно не отобразилось при запуске. Закомментировал строки, которые присваивают ей текст, чтобы проверить, может текст == '' . И тут! При запуске приложения, после нажатия на кнопку "Пропустить рекламу" вылетает "Приложение остановлено". Вот что видим в логе:

```
12-31 15:19:01.789 18522-18799/ru.qwerq.qwerq E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                                                                Process: ru.qwerq.qwerq, PID: 18522
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
                                                                    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
                                                                    at com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask.getPostDataString(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:235)
                                                                    at com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask.invokePost(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:183)
                                                                    at com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask.doInBackground(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:162)
                                                                    at com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask.doInBackground(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:33)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-31 15:19:02.596 18522-18522/ru.qwerq.qwerq E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity ru.qwerq.qwerq.mainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{11588cdb V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:367)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                                                                   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:306)
                                                                   at com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask.onPreExecute(PostResponseAsyncTask.java:151)
                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                                                                   at ru.qwerq.qwerq.mainActivity.get_content(mainActivity.java:598)
                                                                   at ru.qwerq.qwerq.mainActivity.onCreate(mainActivity.java:98)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Откатил файлы вплоть до вчерашних успешных запусков - то же самое! Помогите вернуть смысл жизни...

Comment: У вас некая строка `null` при попытке выяснить её длину в методе `doInBackground` вашей реализации `AsyncTask` - неужели этой информации мало для отлова ошибки? И почему вы не привели проблемный код?

Comment: Потому что я не понимаю, где возникла ошибка.

Comment: Вместо этого я откатил файлы вплоть до вчерашнего дня, тогда приложение запускалось нормально

Comment: Это не помогло. Как я могу знать, где проблемный код?

Comment: Ну у вас там ещё написано такое: `PostResponseAsyncTask.java:151` - т.е. ошибка на 151 строке

Comment: PostResponseAsyncTask - это импортируемый класс, с которым никогда проблем не было. Никаких изменений в нем не производилось

Comment: Вот что находится на его 151 строке

Comment: protected void onPreExecute() {
        if(this.showLoadingMessage) {
            this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.context);
            this.progressDialog.setMessage(this.loadingMessage);
            this.progressDialog.show();
        }

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

Comment: Ну значит так ошибка... ПОпробуйте удалить этот код

Comment: Странно то, что раньше то ошибки там не было, откуда ей там взяться?...

Comment: Для этого может быть тысяча причин. От глюка IDE и вашей невнимательности до бага в яве или андроиде. Лично я ставлю на вашу невнимательность. Проверьте ещё раз ваш код шаг за шагом. Оберните проблемные места в try-catch, выведите полученные ошибки в логи, проёдитесь дебаггером. Чудес, как говорят, не бывает